# How can you use re.sub to replace the content of a capture group with a string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to determine how to use `re.sub` to replace the content of a capture group, but unfortunately, my brain is too small to understand [the API documentation for the `re.sub` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

So far I've managed to successfully isolate the string that I would like to replace using the `re.search` function, but the process of using the `re.sub` function's API properly escapes the past, present, and future capabilities of my fatally, and tragically flawed brain.

I'm able to select the string that I would like to replace using the `re.search` module:

```
import re

RE_SELECT_CURSOR = re.compile(r'.*\(.*after:\s*(?:"*)([A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]+)(?:"*)\s*\).*', flags=re.MULTILINE)

query = """
{{
    users(id: "{}") {{
        things(first: {}, after: null){{
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
"""

#: Identifying the string that I would like to replace (i.e. the "cursor").
matches = re.search(RE_SELECT_CURSOR, query)
if matches:
    cursor = matches.group(1)
    print(cursor)
```

However, once I attempt to replace `null` with`hello`, my naïveté becomes readily apparent.

```
#: Trying to replace the "cursor".
result = re.sub(RE_SELECT_CURSOR, "hello", query)
print(result)
```

This results in the following:

```
{{
    users(id: "{}") {{
hello
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
```

I have tried other approaches, but, none of them have worked - the proper usage of `re.sub` is painfully obvious, but, after reviewing dozens of examples, my brain simply doesn't have the processing power available to understand this.

One such approach was as follows, but, this is laughably incorrect, and I know that I should be embarrassed by my "attempt".

```
RE_REPLACE_GROUP = '.*\(.*after:\s*(?:"*)("hello")(?:"*)\s*\).*'
result = re.sub(RE_SELECT_CURSOR, RE_REPLACE_GROUP, query)
```

Another approach was as follows, but it's also laughably incorrect.

```
import re

RE_SELECT_CURSOR = re.compile(r'.*\(.*after:\s*(?:"*)([A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]+)(?:"*)\s*\).*', flags=re.MULTILINE)

query = """
{{
    organization(id: "{}") {{
        assets(first: {}, after: null){{
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
"""

#: Identifying the string that I would like to replace (i.e. the "cursor").
matches = re.search(RE_SELECT_CURSOR, query)
if matches:
    cursor = matches.group(1)
    query = query.replace("after: {}".format(cursor), "after: {}".format("hello"))
    print(query)
```

This resulted in the following:

```
{{
    organization(id: "{}") {{
        assets(first: {}, after: hello){{
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
```

The result is technically correct, but, it wouldn't tolerate spaces in the wrong place.

Any how I can replace `null` with `hello`?

Comment: You will need to replace everything else you match with itself , or use lookbehind / lookahead. Usually it's easier to capture everything before and after your target, and replace the match with the before stuff, the new value and the after stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can add code to comments, but, I've updated my post with an attempt to replace `null` with `hello` in the original post - it's laughably incorrect, but, it's an attempt, at least.

Comment: the group isn't the same thing as the match. When subbing, the whole match is replaced by hello; not just the group

Comment: Ah, that's where my understanding was painfully, and fatally flawed...I'll have to do some research to see if I'll be able to use `re.sub` here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `group(1)` you extract the group you're interested in, but when using `sub`, the match is *fully* replaced by the replacement. And since the start & end of expression is used to match the context, when subbing, the whole match is replaced by `hello`; not just the group you're interested in.

One way is to create 3 groups, and on match replace the groups by original groups `\1` and `\3` and change the central one by `hello`, like this:

```
import re

RE_SELECT_CURSOR = re.compile(r'(\(.*after:\s*"*)([A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]+)("*\s*\))')  # you don't need MULTILINE flag or leading/trailing .* patterns

query = """
{{
    users(id: "{}") {{
        things(first: {}, after: null){{
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
"""


result = re.sub(RE_SELECT_CURSOR, r"\1hello\3", query)
print(result)
```

prints:

```
{{
    users(id: "{}") {{
        things(first: {}, after: hello){{
            pageInfo {{
                startCursor endCursor hasNextPage
            }}
            edges {{
                node {{
                    id
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In this case what are `\1` and `\3`? I thought that these were capture groups initially, but I only have 1 capture group in my regular expression.

Comment: I have added 2 extra capture groups